# Creating sharepoint discussion list item using REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, discussion-board, discussion

I am consuming sharepoint discussion REST API's in my application.

While creating new discussion (Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25050112/creating-a-sharepoint-2013-discussion-item-using-restful-api)

I need a metadata to be send while creating new discussion like below.

can anyone let me know the way to get metadata for a particular discussion?

"_api/$metadata" is giving metadata but how would i filter metadata for a particular discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking below metadata?

[image]

If so, you can maunally create an item through UI then query it via rest api, it will return the type info:

[image]

BR